# automatically execute python script weekly Azure

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

I encountered a problem within my research for my internship. I made a script that gathered specific data from the instagram API. Is it possible to reproduce this script in a loop weekly via an option in Azure? I can't quite find it.

Thanks in advance!

I hard coded it within the python script option in Azure but I want to automate it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for Time Trigger Azure function which lets you to run a function on a schedule.

See [Timer trigger for Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=in-process&pivots=programming-language-python)  for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Even I was stuck with the same problem and then I got an answer by on of the contributor.

If you are using azure then you can make use of Azure function app with HTTP trigger (to run the python script) and can be integrated in your workflow as well.